# Layout is not working for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-autolayout

The calendar displays for iPhone 5 but does not work for iPhone 6.In iPhone 6 the layout is changed 
this is my code:

```
 calendar = [[DSLCalendarView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 64, 320, 320)];
```

this is image for iPhone 6 its not working 
This the image for iPhone 5 is working.

[image]

Comment: Your iPhone 5 screenshot is missing. As a side not, try to always calculate the screen width instead of using "magic numbers"

Answer (score 0):

You need to adopt auto-layout in order to make your Calendar responsive. Also you have fixed width of calendar. Change

```
CGRectMake(10, 64, 320, 320)
```

to

```
CGRectMake(10,64,self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
```

Comment: Still its not working i used this code. please help me more

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Have you added auto-layout constraints? I cannot give move suggestions based on the information you have provided.

Comment: I want to increase the size of line. if u have any suggestions please help me

Comment: Your question is not relevant to what you need. If you need to customize calendar this link might be helpful for you. http://help.syncfusion.com/ios/sfschedule/appearance-and-styling